How to keep running a function in React until a fetched object's value changes
In my React app I'm fetching an object from my rails backend via an API call that has an array of children objects.  Those children objects get built in the background and could take a minute to populate.  Rails will update the object when the background worker is completed with a new status.  So, the object's status value will change from "pending" to "completed".
I'd like to either keep running the main API call for the parent object until that value changes or run it every few seconds until it's changed.  And then from there I can update the state of value to show those children objects.
How do I keep running a function to fetch this object until the value changes?
In the code below, the value I'm tracking is data.parts_status
Here's what my code looks like:
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [cabinet, setCabinet] = useState(null);
const [checkParts, setCheckParts] = useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    if(loading){
      async function loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId){
        try {
          const data = await fetchCabinet(projectId, cabinetId);
            setCabinet(data);
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(data);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        } loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId);
      }
    }, [cabinet]);

UPDATE.  The useEffect below keeps running despite checkParts being false
  useEffect(() => {
    if(checkParts){
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        async function loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId){
          try {
            const data = await fetchCabinet(projectId, cabinetId);
              setCabinet(data);
              setLoading(false);
              if(data.part_status === "completed"){
                setParts(data.parts);
                setCheckParts(false);
              }
              console.log(data);
            } catch (e) {
              console.log(e);
            }
          } loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId);
      }, MINUTE_MS);
      return () => clearInterval(interval); 
    }
  }, [])


This is a bad idea in the history of bad ideas. Your server ought to have a way of communicating a change to a value if that is very much needed. Don’t poll the server.

I notice that you are not using the state loading, as I understand, if you are using checkParts as a bool state to check condition, then delete state loading. I modified code a little to look cleaner.
As you comment:

Because the rails app slowly adds to the parts array as it builds the
parts. I only want to show it once the status is completed, which
corresponds to a full array.

Only when data.part_status === "completed" is true, checkParts is updated => state change => rerender, so [checkParts] as dependency is correct
  const loadCabinet = async (projectId, cabinetId) => {
    try {
      const data = await fetchCabinet(projectId, cabinetId)
      setCabinet(data)
      setLoading(false) // => delete
      if (data && data.part_status === "completed") {
        // or data?.part_status => prevent crash in this if condition
        setParts(prev => [...prev, ...data.parts]) // also should be this
        setCheckParts(false)
      }
      console.log(data)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkParts) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId), MINUTE_MS)
      return () => clearInterval(interval, loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId))
    }
  }, [checkParts]) //=> this dependency should be checkParts so that component can check state of checkParts changed


This form is the approach I ended up using successfully.

You can use setInterval to accomplish this as follows:
useEffect(
  () => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      // Make your api call/
    }, 1000); // interval in ms

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  },
  []
);



How do I get the useEffect to stop once I get what I want?  I'll edit the above to include the new code.

why dont you add checkParts as array deps
, [checkparts]);. if you pass empty array, passed `checkParts` value wont be updated


@HadiKAR because the rails app slowly adds to the parts array as it builds the parts.  I only want to show it once the status is completed, which corresponds to a full array.

you can use clearInterval(id); this will automatically be done once the component is unmounted but yeah, if you want to do it after your call succedes thats the function you need.

I noticed that you wrote your solutions like this
  useEffect(() => {
    if(checkParts){
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        async function loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId){
          try {
            const data = await fetchCabinet(projectId, cabinetId);
              setCabinet(data);
              setLoading(false);
              if(data.part_status === "completed"){
                setParts(data.parts);
                setCheckParts(false);
              }
              console.log(data);
            } catch (e) {
              console.log(e);
            }
          } loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId);
      }, MINUTE_MS);
      return () => clearInterval(interval); 
    }
  }, [])

this method can retrieve data every MINUTE_MS, but you missed crucial part, the dependency array to stop the interval from running.
  useEffect(() => {
    if(checkParts){
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        async function loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId){
          try {
            const data = await fetchCabinet(projectId, cabinetId);
              setCabinet(data);
              setLoading(false);
              if(data.part_status === "completed"){
                setParts(data.parts);
                setCheckParts(false);
              }
              console.log(data);
            } catch (e) {
              console.log(e);
            }
          } loadCabinet(projectId, cabinetId);
      }, MINUTE_MS);
      return () => clearInterval(interval); 
    }
 -  }, [])
 +  }, [checkParts]) // do this


I do understand checkParts is false after youve done fetching. Without the addition of checkParts in deps array, the useEffect only understand checkParts as true forever.
